# how to join multiple columns or tables into one?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to join multiple columns this way?
btw I'm trying to get all the values even there are no duplicates.

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

result

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
```

EDIT:
i tried

```
SELECT text1 AS col FROM tabla2 UNION ALL SELECT text2 FROM tabla2 UNION ALL SELECT text3 FROM tabla2
```

but I'm not getting the order I need

```
a
d
g
b
e
h
c
f
i
```

Comment: Do you mean use `UNION` ?

Comment: use a union all statement selecting each column.

Comment: @Rildo Gomez put the query you tried to use and the name of the tables please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNION ALL, and perhaps 2 user variables to maintain order.

Assuming you want to keep each value even if duplicated.  If you don't want the duplicates just use `union`.  `Union all` doesn't take a performance hit that a `union` does in that the `union` must execute a distinct.  `Union all` doesn't execute a distinct thus you keep your duplicates.

Now that I know you want the order of the columns preserved... we use two user variables to keep track of which column comes first 2nd 3rd etc... I called this ord.  I then use RN to keep track of which row comes first. but row is irrelevant unless the subqueries are ordered and I don't know what to order by; I just picked the text1.  but since we have to orderby those cols to get eh right row #'s then we had to subquery those tables.

```
SELECT col1
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM (SELECT text1 as col1, 1 as ord, @rn:=@rn+1 as RN
            FROM xtabla2
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0) rn
            ORDER BY text1) col1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT * 
      FROM (SELECT text2, 2, @rn2:=@rn2+1
            FROM xtabla2
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn2:=0) rn
            ORDER BY text2) col2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT * 
      FROM (SELECT text3, 3, @rn3:=@rn3+1
            FROM  xtabla2
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn3:=0) rn3
            ORDER BY text3) col3
      ) OneCol
ORDER BY ord, RN
```

http://rextester.com/KYK54502

Comment: And the expert has spoken

Comment: an... definitely not the :P

Comment: hahahah that's not fair... I do my best, and that's a lot a lot of times ;), but far away from some users... that's true

Comment: I'm making fun of myself I'm no expert.. just a SQL enthusiast.

Comment: I know I know, rep don't come alone, neither score, so, don't be humble, a little more than enthusiast ;) hahaha. Anyway, with users like you answering so fast sometimes is hard! haha! keep doing that, that rules

Comment: this is what I tried SELECT text1 AS col FROM `tabla2` UNION ALL SELECT text2 FROM `tabla2` and I'm getting a ton of errors :/, do you guys see anything wrong with what I did?

Comment: are text1 and text 2 of the same data type?  I don't see anything wrong for the 1st two columns.

Comment: no more errors idk why I was getting that however, I'm sorry for misleading you I don't have number I got strings instead I used numbers in the example but didn't realize my mistake

Comment: To be fair you have to have the outer select for the order by to execute correctly. otherwise the engine thinks the order by is on the last select for col3.

Comment: yes, you are right that's the thing but idk what to put in the order by to make it take the first value of each column like in the example above

Comment: I'm getting the same result as if i wasn't using the order by any ideas why?

Comment: Did you add the 2nd and third columns? Post what you've tried in your initial question.  (notice I added a col aliased as ord  and rn and I order by it first then ord, then rn. But perhaps text isn't what we want to order by and we also need to simulate rowNumber to get the desired order.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the data type is same for your columns

```
Select column1 from table1
union
Select column2 from table1
union
Select column3 from table1
```

Comment: Totally agree :)

Comment: Maybe `union all`? Only `union`  not returns duplicate values

Comment: yeah totally depends on if he wants distinct value or not

Answer (score 0):

You want to use: UNION (without duplicates), UNION ALL (with duplicates)

```
SELECT column_name_1 
FROM your_table_name
UNION ALL
SELECT column_name_2 
FROM your_table_name
SELECT column_name_3 
FROM your_table_name
```

Comment: There's only one table, not 3 different tables.